# Paging 3 - How to handle old APPEND RemoteMediator requests that come trough since beta01?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

Since version `beta01` of Paging 3, when refreshing the PagingData from a `RemoteMediator`, it sometimes happens that the old `APPEND` request from the previous generation is still executed after the refresh has completed. This seems to be expected behavior reading from [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/e754df9ed34341e5aa71e26427244951089e854b%5E%21/paging/common/src/main/kotlin/androidx/paging/RemoteMediatorAccessor.kt?fbclid=IwAR1ED_0_f-1KFQy0TXCnmWvihBTh8SsTY4EaygzKM-90NhZ2i7J9jCvxE00).
When this happens, the old `APPEND` request calls the `RemoteMediator`'s `load` method but with an outdated `PagingState`. This outdated `PagingState` can cause bugs and crashes if we are using the information in it in the load function (for example, the code snippet below uses `lastItemOrNull` to find the `RemoteKeys` for an item in the database). This breaking change (which also breaks the [corresponding codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#19)) is not mentioned in the release notes at all. How are we supposed to handle this?

Here is an example of a RemoteMediator that breaks with `beta01`. The `getRemoteKeyForLastItem` method can return `null` (because the old `PagingState` is looking for a database entry that was deleted in the previous `REFRESH`) causing the `InvalidObjectException` to be thrown.

```
private const val GITHUB_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 1

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class GithubRemoteMediator(
        private val query: String,
        private val service: GithubService,
        private val repoDatabase: RepoDatabase
) : RemoteMediator<Int, Repo>() {

    override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, Repo>): MediatorResult {

        val page = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> GITHUB_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
            LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(true)
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                // this can run with an outdated PagingState from the previous RemoteMediator instance, causing the Exception to be thrown
                val remoteKeys = getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state)
                if (remoteKeys == null || remoteKeys.nextKey == null) {
                    throw InvalidObjectException("Remote key should not be null for $loadType")
                }
                remoteKeys.nextKey
            }

        }

        val apiQuery = query + IN_QUALIFIER

        try {
            val apiResponse = service.searchRepos(apiQuery, page, state.config.pageSize)

            val repos = apiResponse.items
            val endOfPaginationReached = repos.isEmpty()
            repoDatabase.withTransaction {
                if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                    repoDatabase.remoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
                    repoDatabase.reposDao().clearRepos()
                }
                val prevKey = if (page == GITHUB_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1
                val nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1
                val keys = repos.map {
                    RemoteKeys(repoId = it.id, prevKey = prevKey, nextKey = nextKey)
                }
                repoDatabase.remoteKeysDao().insertAll(keys)
                repoDatabase.reposDao().insertAll(repos)
            }
            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = endOfPaginationReached)
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getRemoteKeyForLastItem(state: PagingState<Int, Repo>): RemoteKeys? {
        return state.pages.lastOrNull() { it.data.isNotEmpty() }?.data?.lastOrNull()
                ?.let { repo ->
                    repoDatabase.remoteKeysDao().remoteKeysRepoId(repo.id)
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does InvalidObjectException affect the loading library? I don't think it expects exceptions to occur within its coroutine scope, hence why it exposes MediatorResult.Error (although as append belonging to a generation before the previous refresh, this may as well be expected behavior)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it crashes the app (what we want) or what do you mean?

Comment: If this is standard behavior from Paging 3, then crashing the app seems overkill

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's not standard behavior, it means the programmer messed something up

Answer (score 2):

I talked to Dustin Lam and Yigit Boyar and apparently, the best way to handle this is to make prepend an append not depend on the `PagingState`. This means we should store our remote keys in a table related to a query rather than on the item level.

Exmaple:

```
@Entity(tableName = "search_query_remote_keys")
data class SearchQueryRemoteKey(
    @PrimaryKey val searchQuery: String,
    val nextPageKey: Int
)
```

Comment: what if I don't have a search query simple endpoint with page number and limit?

Comment: Just store the key in your DB.  Or I guess shared preferences or DataStore would also work