# Android Paging3 with RemoteMediator: items appear in the middle of the list or above visible ones, looks messy

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

I have a list of items from API. I'm using Paging3 with *RemoteMedatior* to maintain network with local caching in database using Room. My issue is when data is loading *recyclerView* looks messy and glitchy, items appear in the middle of the list and above visible ones, and *recyclerView* doesn't scroll to the top of the list. [Looks like this](https://s9.gifyu.com/images/device-2021-09-16-134652.gif).
I've tried with various values for *pageSize*, *maxSize*, and *prefetchDistance* for pageConfig but it doesn't help.
*setHasFixedSize* on recylerview also doesn't work.
Flow is collected with *collectLatest* in the fragment. I've tried also normal *collect* and changing *flow* into *liveData*. Same result. Any idea how to correct this?

**load function in RemoteMediator**

```
@ExperimentalPagingApi
class RecipesMediator(
    private val recipesApi: RecipesApi,
    private val appDatabase: RecipesDatabase,
    private val queries: HashMap<String, String>,
) : RemoteMediator<Int, Recipe>() {
    override suspend fun load(loadType: LoadType, state: PagingState<Int, Recipe>): MediatorResult {

    val queryId = queries[QUERY_DIET] + queries[QUERY_MEAL]

    val page = when (loadType) {
        LoadType.REFRESH -> 0
        LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
        LoadType.APPEND -> appDatabase.remoteKeysDao().remoteKeysRecipeId(queryId).nextKey
    }
    
    queries[QUERY_OFFSET] = page.toString()
    queries[QUERY_NUMBER] = "20"

    try {
        val response = recipesApi.getRecipes(queries)

        appDatabase.withTransaction {
            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                appDatabase.remoteKeysDao().clearRemoteKeys()
                appDatabase.recipesDao().clearRecipes()
            }

            val nextKey = page + 20
            val keys = response.recipes.map {

                RemoteKeys(query = queryId, nextKey = nextKey)
            }
            appDatabase.remoteKeysDao().insertAll(keys)
            appDatabase.recipesDao().insertAllRecipes(response.recipes)
        }
        return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = response.recipes.isEmpty())
    } catch (exception: IOException) {
        return MediatorResult.Error(exception)
    } catch (exception: HttpException) {
        return MediatorResult.Error(exception)
    }
}
```

I use string for remote key ids, because when i used item id from API = *LoadType.Append* was called many times and only first page was loaded. Its explained in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169509/paging-3-how-to-handle-old-append-remotemediator-requests-that-come-trough-sin)

*nextPage* is "page + 20" because this API (Spoonacular) doesn't provide pagination, although provides parameters offset (number of results to skip) and number(number of expected results), so i used them for my paging.

**UI states in fragment**

```
 recipesAdapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
        binding.apply {
            recipesProgressBar.isVisible = loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            recipesProgressBar.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading

            recipesRecyclerView.isVisible =loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
            recipesRecyclerView.isVisible =loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading

            buttonRecipesRetry.isVisible =loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Error
            buttonRecipesRetry.isVisible =loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Error

            textViewRecipesError.isVisible =loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.Error
            textViewRecipesError.isVisible =loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Error

            if (loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading &&
                loadState.mediator?.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading &&
                loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached &&
                recipesAdapter.itemCount < 1
            ) {
                recipesRecyclerView.isVisible = false
                textViewEmpty.isVisible = true
            } else {
                textViewEmpty.isVisible = false
            }
        }
    }
```

**Remote Keys**

```
@Entity(tableName = "remoteKeys")
data class RemoteKeys
(@PrimaryKey val query: String, val nextKey: Int)
```

**Remote Keys Dao**

```
@Dao
interface RemoteKeysDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertAll(remoteKey: List<RemoteKeys>)

@Query("SELECT * FROM remoteKeys WHERE `query` = :query")
suspend fun remoteKeysId(query: String): RemoteKeys

@Query("DELETE FROM remoteKeys")
suspend fun clearRemoteKeys()
}
```

Comment: How are you sorting the list when you query the cache from PagingSource? This is usually attributed to remote fetching items out of order than your PagingSource expects

Comment: hi Dlam. Thanks for comment. Well, im not sorting it at all. I'm getting in directly as it is from database. Snippet from my dao:   

  @Query("SELECT * FROM foodRecipe")
    fun getRecipesPagingSource(): PagingSource<Int, Recipe>

Comment: That seems problematic because you have no guarantees on the order you load the data in. The way RemoteMediator works is by updating the backing dataset and invalidating Paging, so it reloads from the DB to pick up the new items. This maintains a single source of truth, but if you don't sort the results, you might end up with the newly fetched items appearing in the middle of the list. You want something like `@Query("SELECT * FROM foodRecipe ORDER BY id")`.

Comment: If your backend doesn't give you a canonical way to order your items, you can always track yourself based on the index from the response - we have an example of this on github here: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/PagingWithNetworkSample